# Tor fails to initilise after installation

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I am on Windows 11 and suddenly lost Tor from system. I downloaded the installation file  (Torbrowser-install-win64-11.5.1_en-US_2.exe) but during installation (to my desktop) I get this message=  "The procedure entry point RSA_get0_d could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\users\boxer\Desktop\Tor Browser\browser\TorBrowser\Tor\Tor.exe"
At this point it stops dead.
Firefox is working OK and event viewer is silent. Have deleted and re-installed several time but always the same.

Comment: related: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/33702